# H2 failing to process valid MySQL - CONVERT(images.X USING UTF8) as X

Tags: mysql, h2

When researching this issue, it doesn't help that "convert" is such a generic word.

I have a legacy app with working MySQL, but the database code is untested. I'm trying to add unit tests using an H2 DB. I am getting the following error for my query:

`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT ...<verbose query>`

When I remove this part of the query, it works: `CONVERT(images.USER_DATA USING UTF8) as USER_DATA`, though of course other things fail.

Is there a way to get H2 to recognize the CONVERT function or maybe another good way of converting this data?

Test properties:

```
images.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:images;MODE=MYSQL;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:init.sql'
images.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```

Comment: https://phauer.com/2017/dont-use-in-memory-databases-tests-h2/

Comment: The entire point of using h2 is for quick feedback cycles during development. You might as well say don't use Java

Comment: But you are not testing the code that will run in production, so the tests are pretty much meaningless.

Comment: "Not ideal" does not mean they're meaningless, and you're not telling me anything I don't already know. If I could avoid using H2 and get a quick feedback cycle, I would 100% do so, but I can't. If that means having to add another layer of integration tests that more properly exercises the database, that sucks a lot, but just because this stack is flawed in that way is no reason to throw out tests with a quick feedback cycle, even if those tests are flawed.

Comment: Note that this is especially true considering the developers on the team I'm consulting with have already demonstrated that if they have to write slow-feedback cycle tests for their database, they either don't write them at all or they're not remotely comprehensive, which is the entire reason I'm here trying to figure out a solution that will get them to test their code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the db was using BLOB for json instead of TEXT. Changed that, then I didn't have to worry about this anymore.